# Error converting string to date field in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

As you can infer from the above , When I try to convert the string , it gives error.

Tried below codes but got same error as,*day is not defined,*

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'],format='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

As SO memeber suggested,I edited code but index stills the string, did not convert to day

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to create another column, then just this will do:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still gets string in index column, please refer the edited question

Comment: You didn't do what I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `df['day']` actually appears to be your index. To fix this, you'd want to call pd.to_datetime on your index:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

I could tell it was your index because pandas offsets the row height of the columns for the index column and the other columns. Take this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['a','b','c']})

df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
```

outputs:

```
   b
a
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

Comment: Thanks, as it is index it should have been done as you suggested